# how to add image inside an array in angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

Here is my plunker link:
https://plnkr.co/edit/oo05d6H6AxuJGXBAUQvr?p=preview

I'm trying to develop an application where I have elements inside an array.  When I click on each element details will be displayed, but I'm not able to display image,

How can I add an image attribute inside an array and again display it using html page?

script.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.controller('mobileController', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        name: 'Iphone',price:70000,rating:'*****',image: 'how to add image here'
    }, {
        name: 'Oneplus',price:60000,rating:'****',image: 'how to add image here'
    }, {
        name: 'Samsung',price:50000,rating:'***',image: 'how to add image here'
    }, {
        name: 'Sony',price:40000,rating:'***',image: 'how to add image here'
    }, {
        name: 'Moto',price:20000,rating:'****',image: 'how to add image here'
    }];
});

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/item/:itemName/:itemPrice/:itemRating/:itemImage', {
          templateUrl: 'details.html',
          controller: 'ItemCtrl'
      });
});

app.controller('ItemCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {
      $scope.itemName = $routeParams.itemName;
      $scope.itemPrice = $routeParams.itemPrice;
      $scope.itemRating = $routeParams.itemRating;
      $scope.itemImage = $routeParams.itemImage;
  }
]);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mobileController">
        <h2> Welcome to Mobile Store</h2>
        <p>Search:<input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items|filter:test">
                <a href="#/item/{{item.name}}/{{item.price}}/{{item.rating}}/{{item.image}}">{{ item.name }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

details.html

```
<p>ItemName: {{itemName}}</p>
<p> ItemPrice: {{itemPrice}}</p>
<p>ItemRating:{{itemRating}}</p>
<p>{{itemImage}}</p>
```

Comment: You can store the path and use `ng-src`

Comment: where to store the path can you elaborate?

Comment: replace `how to add image here` with `/pah/to/image.png` then you can use `<img src="{{itemImage}}">`

Answer (score 1):

The better way to add images is to use ng-src in angularjs.e.g.You can give a relative path to your images. My images sit in a content folder './content/Images/T1_1.jpg' and in your html add
`<img ng-src="{{item.imageSrc}}" alt="{{item.p_variation}}">`

Comment: is there any way that i can add images in plunker and then give the path?

Comment: you can use base64-encoded data-uri or use imgur to do that for you. plnkr i guess doesnt support non-text formats

Answer (score 0):

Your detail.html change to like below..

```
<p>ItemName: {{itemName}}</p>
<p> ItemPrice: {{itemPrice}}</p>
 <p>ItemRating:{{itemRating}}</p>
  <img ng-src="itemImage">
```

Comment: your normal path is enough. like image:"path1/photo.png"

Comment: you mean the path of images in my desktop?

Comment: Put your images in your project folder.. Then give path.

Answer (score 0):

Make some small changes to your `details.html` and `script.js` like this -

**script.js**

```
  app.controller('mobileController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    name: 'Iphone',price:70000,rating:'*****',image: 'www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'
  }, {
    name: 'Oneplus',price:60000,rating:'****',image: 'path/to/imgresource'
  }];
});
```

**details.html**

```
<p>ItemName: {{itemName}}</p>
<p> ItemPrice: {{itemPrice}}</p>
<p>ItemRating:{{itemRating}}</p>
<img ng-src="{{item.image}}" alt="some text">
```

Note: Images should be accessed from your local server. For Ex-

```
http://localhost:8080/img/foo.png
```

Comment: image is not getting displayed,some text in the alt is getting displayed

Comment: is it because plunker does not support images?

Comment: Try using the path in your project instead of plunker as will not understand the relative path of the image that you might be giving in the "ng-src". Or please share the image <img> tag you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the way you are trying to do it is possible because your image path will also have /.

Have a look at this working plunkr.
https://plnkr.co/edit/rCO96V?p=preview

Pass only the name or some id

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in items|filter:test"><a href="#/item/{{item.name}}">{{ item.name }}</a>
```

and then

```
angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
     if(item.name==$routeParams.itemName){
          $scope.itemName = item.name;
          $scope.itemPrice = item.price;
          $scope.itemRating = item.rating;
          $scope.itemImage = item.image;
    }
});
```

Comment: hey thanks! but how did u give that google image link ?I'm trying to give iPhone images link but I'm not getting in png format

Comment: As you can see at the plunkr I have posted at script.js file I set the image path and then at details.html <img src="{{itemImage}}">

Answer (score 0):

name: 'Iphone',
rating: '*****',
image: `../assets/imagelink.jpg`

imagelink is whatever image file is

ex: I have an image called `silk-images.png`
in the array would be

image: `../assets/silk-images.png`

in my HTML I had an array for *ngFfor='let stores of store'
{{stores.image}}